# Allow access premium features through telco billing in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I need to create an iOS application that anyone should be able to download the app.  But this app contains premium user capability.

So with the premium user capability user can purchase and access couple of features by purchasing.

When it comes to payment module:
 I need it to be integrated from tel-co billing, 
 How it should be?

```
 According to following steps :
1) User send request to the BO 
2) BO will make the deduction from telco (bill to users post-paid connection), 
3) I will receive the response , and based on that i will allow access  features.
```

**My question is**, will the apple allow this process , Since I know its bit tricky things when it comes to in-app purchase with iOS . I know how apple restrict things whith digital content. will apple allow my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Apple requires your in app purchases to be administered through their app store. They will most likely reject your app if you implement it like that. Also from your phrasiology in step 3 it sounds as if you would be approving features yourself by hand, this would really negatively impact your user experience (especially considering any sort of scaling). Personally, I wont pay for any "paid features" that aren't provided through Apple's store. Check this out: https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial